# Difficulty navigating shoelaces

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I am designing a shoe. I had a problem with the design of the straps and it seems like a very difficult job.
I want to cross the straps crosswise according to the lower part of the image.
[image]

I tried to edit the different parts of the shoelace in edit mode, but it seems that the idea is not good at all. Is there a more logical solution to this?

[image]

As you can see, manual editing the mesh is not clean idea to do this.

---

**Update**

According to the two methods proposed in the answers, the final output turned out like this:
[image]

Comment: have you thought about using a curve instead of a mesh? or a mesh with Array and Curve modifiers?

Comment: Hello. No i tried to use physics for Falling end of the shoelaces, and also bend modifier for bending the middle; but its hard to control

Comment: so, use a curve, bevel it, you can enable the snap option to make it stick to the shoe surface

Comment: I'm trying it right now :) @moonboots

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Shoelaces are typically a work for curves in my opinion. You just need to bevel your curve in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Geometry > Bevel*. If your lace is a bit more complicated than just a simple tube, create a mesh that will be your segment, duplicate it with an *Array* modifier and make it follow the curve with a *Curve* modifier.

[image]

Comment: Wow that is so great; Thanks so much :)

Comment: You're not telling me you cooked up that boot in 20 minutes?

Comment: well, not just me, my whole team and I !!

Answer (score 12):

A time saving approach.

[image]

From left to right:

- A mesh with few vertices and edges placed at each turning point.
- Convert the mesh to curve, change its type to "bezier" and its control points to "automatic".
- Add a curve to the lace object or simply use bevel around the curve.
- Adjust the control points in their positions and individual length to tighten the curve.

Base geometry is just like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could also start with a curve